# In SQL Server I did't find any examples how to convert int data type to date data type

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with `INT` datatype column and my data is something like this

```
valid_to_day(int)
------------
20150301
20150101
```

I want to get previous date of this column, if I perform -1 to the above data 
the data is something like this

```
valid_to_day
------------
20150300
20150100
```

Expected data

```
valid_to_day
------------
20150228
20141231
```

Please can anyone help

Thanks in advance

satish

Comment: Why are you storing your dates as integers, which will make handling this much more difficult?  You should store your dates as...dates.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't store dates like that.

The `Date` datatype is more compact, ensures you have no invalid dates, and can be used with date functions.

Hopefully you need this so you can fix your schema.

One method which does not rely on casting to string would be

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(valid_to_day/10000, valid_to_day%10000/100, valid_to_day%100)
```

And of course now it is the proper datatype you can just use `DATEADD` to get the previous day.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,
                -1, 
                DATEFROMPARTS(valid_to_day/10000, valid_to_day%10000/100, valid_to_day%100)
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dateadd function along with convert type of 112

```
declare @d int = 20150301

select  convert(int, convert(varchar(10), dateadd(d,-1,convert (date, convert(varchar(10),@d), 112)),112))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert first **INT** to **VARCHAR** and then **to** **DATE**:

```
DECLARE @d INT = 20150101

SELECT CAST(CAST(@d AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE)
SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,CAST(CAST(@d AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE))
SELECT 
    REPLACE
    (
        CAST
        (
            DATEADD(d,-1,CAST
                        (
                            CAST(@d AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE)
                        ) 
            AS VARCHAR(10)
        )
        ,'-',''
    )
```